# Adding element to new array using assign by addition, but original array value dynamically changes the new array elements too

Tags: arrays, powershell

First post, I've been researching this all day and I'm at my wits end!  I have an array called $Global:CBCGroups that I want to contain the value of an ever-changing variable called $Global:CBCTempHolder.  Whenever $Global:CBCTempHolder is changed, I want it to add it's contents to the array $Global:CBCGroups using += (ie:

```
$Global:CBCGroups += $Global:CBCTempHolder
```

The columns in CBCGroups are CBCGroup, and Element.  The same is present in $Global:CBCTempHolder, but the value changes in every "For" statement.  Here is the code:

```
$Global:CBCGroups = @()


for ($z = 0; $z -lt $Global:UniqueCCData.count; $z +=1)
{
If ($Global:UniqueCCData[$z]."AD Group".Contains("CBC_CBC_") -eq $True)
{
        $Global:CBCTempHolder = @(0) * 1 | select CBCGroup,Element
        $Global:CBCTempHolder.CBCGroup = $Global:UniqueCCData[$z]."AD Group"
        $Global:CBCTempHolder.Element = $z
        $Global:CBCGroups += $Global:CBCTempHolder
        $Global:UniqueCCData[$z]."AD Group" = $Global:UniqueCCData[$z]."AD Group".Replace("CBC_CBC_","CBC.CBC")

    }
}
```

So, basically what is happening is whenever I add a new element to $Global:CBCGroups via:

```
$Global:CBCGroups += $Global:CBCTempHolder
```

I am noticing that whenever I change the value of $Global:CBCTempHolder and then manually change the values of $Global:CBCTempHolder.CBCGroup to anything, add say 5 elements in a row using the assign by addition operator, and then change the value of $Global:CBCTempHolder again manually, it changes the last 5 elements in $Global:CBCGroups to the same value!  I need each element in $Global:CBCGroups to maintain it's value from the time when it was added to the array.

I realize $Global:CBCTempHolder is not a true array, but it contains the two named elements that I need to have added to a new list.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have also experimented with wrapping the variable to the right of the += assign by addition operator with $() to only use the value, but this still seems to behave the same way, dynamically changing the new array element whenever the base variable's values change (ie.):

    $Global:CBCGroups += $($Global:CBCTempHolder)

Comment: I feel like you're not showing us all the code. Where do you assign a value to `$Global:UniqueCCData`?

Comment: I was importing the value of $Global:UniqueCCData via import-csv from a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that exhibits the issue:

```
$UniqueCCData = @()
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "Domain Users" }
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "CBC_CBC_Enterprise Admins" }
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "CBC_CBC_Help Desk" }
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "CBC_CBC_Marketing" }
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "CBC_CBC_Sales" }
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "Domain Admins" }
$CBCGroups = @()
for ($z = 0; $z -lt $UniqueCCData.count; $z += 1)
{
    if ($UniqueCCData[$z]."AD Group".Contains("CBC_CBC_") -eq $True)
    {
        $CBCTempHolder = @(0) * 1 | select CBCGroup,Element
        $CBCTempHolder.CBCGroup = $UniqueCCData[$z]."AD Group"
        $CBCTempHolder.Element = $z
        $CBCGroups += $CBCTempHolder
        $UniqueCCData[$z]."AD Group" = $UniqueCCData[$z]."AD Group".Replace("CBC_CBC_","CBC.CBC")
    }
}
$CBCTempHolder.CBCGroup = "CBC_CBC_VIPs"
$CBCTempHolder.Element = 5
$CBCGroups += $CBCTempHolder
$CBCGroups
```

Here's the output:

```
CBCGroup                    Element
--------                    -------
CBC_CBC_Enterprise Admins         1
CBC_CBC_Help Desk                 2
CBC_CBC_Marketing                 3
CBC_CBC_VIPs                      5
CBC_CBC_VIPs                      5
```

The problem is that a reference to the object is assigned. So when the object changes, any objects that are referencing it also appear to change. The way to work around this to assign unique objects to each index of CBCGroups. Here's how I'd solve it:

```
function CBC_clone($group, $i)
{
    $temp = @(0) * 1 | select CBCGroup,Element
    $temp.CBCGroup = $group.Replace("CBC_CBC_","CBC.CBC")
    $temp.Element = $i
    return $temp
}
$UniqueCCData = @()
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "Domain Users" }
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "CBC_CBC_Enterprise Admins" }
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "CBC_CBC_Help Desk" }
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "CBC_CBC_Marketing" }
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "CBC_CBC_Sales" }
$UniqueCCData += new-object psobject -property @{ "AD Group" = "Domain Admins" }
$CBCGroups = @()
for ($z = 0; $z -lt $UniqueCCData.count; $z += 1)
{
    if ($UniqueCCData[$z]."AD Group".Contains("CBC_CBC_") -eq $True)
    {
        $CBCGroups += (CBC_clone $UniqueCCData[$z]."AD Group" $z)
    }
}
$CBCGroups += (CBC_clone "CBC_CBC_VIPs" 5)
$CBCGroups
```

This produces the desired output:

```
CBCGroup                 Element
--------                 -------
CBC.CBCEnterprise Admins       1
CBC.CBCHelp Desk               2
CBC.CBCMarketing               3
CBC.CBCSales                   4
CBC.CBCVIPs                    5
```

Comment: Basically in my code, if I manually type $CBCGroups += $CBCTempHolder after the script has finished running, say I type it 4 times... whenever I change the value of $CBCTempholder.CBCGroup or $CBCTempHolder.Element, it automatically changes the last 4 entries of $CBCGroups.  I actually just want it to leave the existing entries alone, and simply add the new element to the array without changing everything else.

Comment: Simply amazing, I don't know why I never thought of using a function to return the value!  Suppose that's why I reached out for help :)

Really thanks a million, saved me much frustration.

Brandon